# Opting out of searching in online resources

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I'm new to Unity. I've just installed Ubuntu Desktop LTS 14.04. 
In the top-left corner there's an Ubuntu icon,
when I click on it it pops up a search input box saying:

> Search your computer and online resources

I'd like to remove online resources.
At the right-hand side I noticed a **Filter results** dropdown,
where I removed all the unwanted sources and left only **Applications**.
But when I enter the letters "ter" in the search box (for "terminal"),
the categories I previously unselected pop back,
and I see results like News, More suggestions (shopping), Reference and many others.
(See the screenshot below.)

- How can I opt out of searching in online resources?
- What's name of this search thingy?
- What's the keyboard shortcut to bring up this search box easily?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of this search box is **Dash**.

To turn off online search Go to System Settings- Privacy - Search results. Mark 'When searching in Dash - Include online search results' as 'Off'.

Furthermore, on the Dash go to the second menu from the bottom left- Applications lens. On the  Filter Results go to Sources and unselect Software Center.

To bring the search box press Super Key.

Answer (score 2):

To bring up the Dash/search box use the Super Key/Windows key. If you ever forget a shortcut press and Hold the Super Key and you will see all Ubuntu's Keyboard shortcuts appear.